# How to find the matrix $A$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> Let $S$ be the shear parallel to the line $l:5x-y=0$ in the direction $\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 5 \end{bmatrix}$ .
>
> Let $S(\vec{x})=A\vec{x} $. Find $A$.

**My try**:

I dont understand how to do it.
Any line parallel to $l:5x-y=0$ is given by $5x-y+k=0$
How to find $A$.

Any help.

Comment: Two possible approaches are 1) Algebraic: find a change of basis that turns this into a shear that you do know how to compute and 2) Geometric: figure out what this shear does to the unit square. The sides of the resulting paralellogram are the images of the standard basis vectors.

Comment: It seems like there’s something missing from this problem, though: how much of a shear are you meant to apply, or is that supposed to be a parameter left unknown?